# how to app keep running on background using ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I need app is run on background mode.

Actually i used this plugin

```
  ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode

  npm install --save @ionic-native/background-mode

  this.backgroundMode.enable();
```

But its not work.

I need app is run on background mode when app is killed.

I have no idea.

Kindly Advise me,

Thanks

Comment: you can check this pool https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-make-a-background-process-when-app-is-not-running/41859

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I also tried this.still not wrk

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand you still need to subscribe to an event or method.

look at this comprehensive tutorial: https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-background-mode/

Make sure you have done the following:

Added the module to your app.module.ts files imports

Add the import to the app.module providers

import again in the .ts file you are trying to make run in the background

enable background mode

subscribe to an event or method that should run in the background

let us know if all of this is in place and its still not working.